# regex duplicate spintax

Tags: php, regex

I'm new in PHP.

I want make a article spinner using PHP.

Before the string process using **spintax** function, I want replace some text with its synonyms.

E.G:

```
$text = "Mother fry a turkey in the cooking room accompanied by a father who makes drinks and mother really happy.";
```

result:

```
$newstring = "{mother|mama} {fry|cook} {a turkey|the chicken} in the {the cooking room|kitchen} {accompanied by|with} {father|papa} who {makes|prepare} {coffee|drinks} and {mother|mama} really {happy|fun}.";
```

I'm not use mysql database, but only use txt file and only using fopen for get the synonyms.

but the result was very bad,

E.G:

```
$newstring = "{mother|mama} {fry|cook} {a turkey|the chicken} in the {the cooking room|kitchen} {accompanied by|with} {father|papa} who {makes|prepare} {coffee|drinks} and {{mother|mama}|mama} really {happy|fun}.";
```

I use regex pattern like this:

```
$text = preg_replace( "/\b$search\b/sui", $replace, $text );
```

What regex pattern should I use to avoid duplicate replacement like that?

Anybody can help me?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks before.

Comment: Bad English is forgivable, bad formatting is not! Please edit your question to include proper formatting. There is an editing help link if you are unsure of how to do so.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what is formating you mean...

Comment: Google translator is your friend but paste "formatting" not formating :-). If you click on "edit" (under question's tags) you can "format" your text using the editor. For example you can wrap the code parts using the code markup button of the editor and so on...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a totally blind man, and I can't see how it looks...

Answer (score 0):

Lets get out of the old thought patterns:

```
$text = "Father roasts mother in the cooking room accompanied by a turkey who makes drinks and the turkey is really happy.";
```

You need an associative array and to build an alternation to match each word in the list and replace all of them in a single pass using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$corr = [ 'father' => '{father|daddy}', 'roasts' => '{roasts|cooks}', 'cooking room' => '{cooking room|kitchen}' ];
$words = array_keys($corr);
rsort($words);
$pattern = '~\b(?:' . implode('|', $words) . ')\b~ui';    

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($corr) {
    $word = strtolower($m[0]); // better with mb_strtolower() if available
    return $corr[$word];
}, $text);
```

The u modifier forces the regex engine to read the string as a unicode string encoded in UTF-8 (useful if your string uses characters out of the ASCII range).

[demo](https://eval.in/757952)

Note that sorting the array of words in reverse order is important since the regex engine returns the first branch that succeeds in an alternation.